# LISP - get last list of a list

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to figure out how to obtain the *last* (non-empty) list from within another list, or return `nil` if there is no such list (recursively).  This is an homework assignment, and as such I am looking for help on the method, not necessarily the code for it.  Example:

```
(lastele '(1 (2 3) 4 5))  ;=> (2 3)
(lastele '(1 (2 3) (4 5)) ;=> (4 5)
(lastele '(1 2 3 4 5))    ;=> NIL
```

I was trying to run through the list, and if I encountered a sublist, I would check to see if the rest of the list contained any more non-empty sublists, if it did, continue with setting the list to that, and repeating until we had a null list.

```
(defun lastele2 (L)
  (if (null L)
    '()
    (if (hasMoreLists (rest L))
      (lastele2 (rest L))
      (first L))))
```

It seems as if I can't get `hasMoreLists` to work, though. Returning `t` or `f` within is just erroring.  Is this the best way to go about this?

Comment: How about indenting your code a bit better?

Comment: I had an answer for this interesting homework assignment and was ready to click `Send`.  But before I could, the dog ate everything I had typed. ;-)

Comment: @RainerJoswig How about not being so rude when I'm clearly new to LISP and asking for help?

Comment: @Drew Yes, it's an assignment problem, but that's why I am asking for help on the method, not necessarily the code itself. I don't like being spoon fed code, that's no way to learn.

Comment: Good reply.  Looks like you're getting some help now.

Comment: What's 'rude' about asking to indent your code? Why should everybody here look at that code and have to export it and to indent it. Indentation is very important to make Lisp code readable. You could save us that work and invest a bit more effort writing down your question. If you want to post source, make sure that it is readable. You can still do it. You can edit your question and indent the source code properly.

Comment: It seems like the most specific question here as about the implementation of `hasMoreLists`.  Where's the code for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, note that you're implicitly assuming that none of the sublists are the *empty list*;  if they could be the empty list, then `nil` is an ambiguous result, because you can't tell whether your function returned `nil` because there were no sublists, or because there were, and the last one was empty.  E.g.,

```
(fn '(1 2 3 4 5))  ;=> nil because there are no sublists  
(fn '(1 2 3 () 5)) ;=> nil because there are sublists, and the last one is nil
```

So, under the assumption that there are no *non-null* sublists in the toplevel list, we can continue.

### A non-homework solution using standard functions

You don't need to write this.  You can just use [`find-if`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_find_.htm) with the predicate [`listp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_listp.htm) and specify that you want to search from the end by using the keyword argument `:from-end t`:

```
CL-USER> (find-if 'listp '(1 (2 3) 4 5) :from-end t)
(2 3)
CL-USER> (find-if 'listp '(1 (2 3) (4 5)) :from-end t)
(4 5)
CL-USER> (find-if 'listp '(1 2 3 4 5) :from-end t)
NIL
```

### Writing your own

If you need to write something like this, your best bet is to use a recursive function that searches a list and keeps track of the most recent list element that you've seen as the result (the starting value would be `nil`) and when you finally reach the end of the list, you'd return that result.  E.g.,

```
(defun last-list (list)
  (labels ((ll (list result)                 ; ll takes a list and a "current result"
             (if (endp list)                 ; if list is empty
                 result                      ; then return the result
                 (ll (cdr list)              ; else continue on the rest of list
                     (if (listp (car list))  ; but with a "current result" that is
                         (car list)          ; (car list) [if it's a list]
                         result)))))         ; and the same result if it's not
    (ll list nil)))                          ; start with list and nil
```

The local function `ll` here is tail recursive, and some implementations will optimize it into a loop, but would be more idiomatic to use a genuine looping construct.  E.g., with `do`, you'd write:

```
(defun last-list (list)
  (do ((result nil (if (listp (car list)) (car list) result))
       (list list (cdr list)))
      ((endp list) result)))
```

If you don't want to use labels, you can define this as two functions:

```
(defun ll (list result)
  (if (endp list)
      result
      (ll (cdr list)
          (if (listp (car list))
              (car list)
              result))))

(defun last-list (list)
  (ll list nil))
```

Alternatively, you could make `last-list` and `ll` be the same functions by having `last-list` take the `result` as an optional parameter:

```
(defun last-list (list &optional result)
  (if (endp list)
      result
      (last-list (cdr list)
                 (if (listp (car list))
                     (car list)
                     result))))
```

In all of these cases, the algorithm that you're implementing is essentially iterative.  It's

> **Input:** *list*
> *result* ← **nil**
> **while** ( *list* is not empty )
>   **if** ( first element of *list* is a list )
>     *result* ← first element of *list*
>   **end if**
>   *list* ← rest of *list*
> **end while**
> **return** *result*

### Something based on the code in the question

We can still find something that's a bit closer to your original approach (which will use more stack space), though.  First, your original code with proper indentation (and some newlines, but there's more flexible in coding styles there):

```
(defun lastele2 (L)
  (if (null L)
      '()
      (if (hasMoreLists (rest L))
          (lastele2 (rest L))
          (first L))))
```

The approach it *looks* like you're trying to use is to define the last sublist of a list `L` as:

- `nil`, if `L` is empty;
- if `(rest L)` has some sublists, whatever the last sublist of `(rest L)` is; and
- if `(rest L)` doesn't have some sublists, then `(first L)`.

That last line isn't quite right, though.  It needs to be

- if `(rest L)` doesn't have some sublists, then `(first L)` *if `(first L)` is a list*, and `nil` otherwise.

Now, you've already got a way to check whether `(rest L)` *has* any (non-null) sublists;  you just check whether `(lastele2 (rest L))` returns you `nil` or not.  If it returns `nil`, then it didn't contain any (non-null) sublists.  Otherwise it returned one of the lists.  This means that you can write:

```
(defun last-list (list)
  (if (endp list)                             ; if list is empty
      nil                                     ; then return nil
      (let ((result (last-list (rest list)))) ; otherwise, see what (last-list (rest list)) returns
        (if (not (null result))               ; if it's not null, then there were more sublists, and 
            result                            ; last-list returned the result that you wantso return it
            (if (listp (first list))          ; otherwise, if (first list) is a list
                (first list)                  ; return it  
                nil)))))                      ; otherwise return nil
```

This is implementing the an essentially recursive algorithm;  the value of the subproblem is returned, and then *lastList* returns a value after examining it that result:

> **Function:** *lastList(list)*
> **if** ( *list* is empty )
>    **return nil**
> **else**
>    *result* ← *lastList(list)*
>   **if** ( *result* is not **nil** )
>      **return** *result*
>   **else if** ( first element of *list* is a list )
>      **return** first element of *list*
>   **else**
>      **return nil**
>   **end if**
> **end if**

Comment: I'm aware of the built in functions, however I need to write it to understand the methods behind it (also homework)

Comment: Now only if we were allowed to use labels =(

Comment: @Nexion There's no mention in the _question_ that this is an assignment, nor that you were aware of the built in functions.  With that clarification, I don't mind showing and discussing a recursive solution, but do note that StackOverflow is for "professional and enthusiast programmers".  That certainly includes students, but it is important to indicate all the requirements of a problem in the question.

Comment: @Nexion can you use `PROG` and `GO`? :)

Comment: @Nexion `labels` is only syntax for defining a local function;  you can use another `defun`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I will indicate future questions regarding assignments as such, sorry for the confusion. Will edit OP to reflect the situation for those who look up similar questions later.

Comment: Huzzah :D I understand it now. Thank you for spelling everything out so clearly. All is working as intended. You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the best way to go about this. To find whether the rest of list has more lists, you need to search it - and if it has, you restart scanning over the rest of your list.

I.e. you do a lot of back and forth.

Instead, [just search along](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/mac_dolist.html), and update a side variable to point to any list you find along the way.

```
(defun lastele (lst &aux a)          ; a is NIL initially
  (dolist (e lst a)                  ; return a in the end
    (if (consp e) (setq a e))))
```

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_dae.htm) `&aux` is really useful.

Comment: @Sylwester Common Lisp is a *practical* language.